# MongoDB - alterar valor de objeto dentro de array de objetos

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Tenho uma collection em mongodb chamada `users` que contem o campo (que é um array de objetos) `adress`. Tenho o seguinte trecho de código para fazer a substituição e alterar na base de dados:

```js
async updateAdress(input) {
  const { idUser, idAdress, adressInfo } = input;
  let user = await User.findById(idUser);
  let counter = 0;

  console.log(adressInfo);
  let old = user.adressInfo;
  user.adressInfo.forEach(adress => {

    if (adress.id == idAdress) {
      old[counter] = adressInfo;

    }
    counter++;
  });
  console.log(old);
  return User.findByIdAndUpdate(idUser, { $set: { adressInfo: old } }, { new: true }).catch(
    err => console.error(err)
  );
}
```

No `console.log` os valores estão direitos, mas ao inserir na base de dados, o objeto editado fica com todos os campos `null` e troca o `id`. Alguém sabe o porque?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer atualizar um registro que está contido dentro de um array, certo? Atualizar um elemento especifico que é um `address`. Se for, por que não simplificar usando o operador `$` do MongoDB?

Comment: quero atualizar um objeto que está dentro de um array, pode me indicar a documentação ou como posso pesquisar acerca desse operador $?

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que seu `users` tenha um campo de `address` como um array, vamos demonstrar o caso de exemplo:

```js
users: {
   name: '...',
   age: 20,
   // ...
   address: [
      {
        _id: '123',
        street: '...'
        // ...
      },
      {
        _id: '456',
        street: '...'
        // ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Pela `updateAdress`, entendemos que você quer atualizar um objeto de `address` específico. Neste caso a sua funcão poderia ser um pouco mais simplificada, sem haver a necessidade de fazer um loop `forEach` e ter que usar `if (adress.id == idAdress) {...}`. O MongoDB oferece um recurso que permite atualizar um Objeto dentro de um array. Usamos o [*The positional $ operator*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). Ele possui uma sintaxe bem simples para indicar qual objeto deverá ser atualizado. No exemplo da documentacão, temos um exemplo:

Temos o documento:

```
{
  _id: 4,
  grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 8 }
  ]
}
```

E queremos atualizar o objeto que tem o `grade` igual a `90` e ajustar o `std` para `7`. Fazemos o uso do `$`:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 90 },  // filtramos o objeto incluso no array aqui
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 7 } } // usamos o "$" aqui
)
```

Resultado após o update:

```
{
   "_id" : 4,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 85, "std" : 7 }
   ]
}
```

Agora vamos adptar para o seu código. Vamos usar o método `findOneAndUpdate` do Mongoose. A lógica final seria algo assim:

```js
async updateAdress(input) {
  const { idUser, idAdress, adressInfo } = input;
  let user = await User.findById(idUser);
  let counter = 0;
  //                                              ↓↓↓ filtramos o objeto no array aqui
  return User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: idUser, 'address._id': idAdress  }, 
  //                     ↓↓↓ atualiza o primeiro documento que fez o "match" da query
  //                         e associa um novo valor a ele ("addressInfo")
    { $set: { 'adressInfo.$': addressInfo } }, { new: true }
  ).catch(
    err => console.error(err)
  );
}
```

O operador posicional `$` identifica um elemento em um array para atualizar sem especificar explicitamente a posição do elemento no array.

Detalhes:

- o operador posicional `$` atua como um marcador para o primeiro elemento que corresponde ao documento de consulta, e
- o campo array deve aparecer como parte do documento de consulta.

#### Obs:

Note que eu usei o `_id`, pois no geral esse é o nome dos id's que o mongoose cria. Não sei como você estruturou se código, mas creio que se você fizer as adaptacões, esta resposta pode ser útil.

> No console.log os valores estão direitos, mas ao inserir na base de dados, o objeto editado fica com todos os campos `null` e troca o `id`

fica difícil entender sem analisar os logs, mas esse problema pode ser porque não foi encontrado o `id` de usuário especificado. O mongoose não altera os valores de `id`, então se um novo `id` foi criado, é porque um novo elemento foi criado, isso por causa do `{ new: true }`. Teste novamente seu código, substitura `findByIdAndUpdate` por `findOneAndUpdate`, etc...